# Edge Conditional White Space Issue R

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning, stringr

I'm trying to clean a long character vector and am getting an edge case where separating the following format of text isn't possible: 
$4.917.10%

The issue is how to set a conditional whitespace so that the text looks like this: $4.91 7.10%.

The vector is called "test9" and the script that cleans the typical situations where there is a "-" in front of % is:

```
gsub("(?=[-])", " ", test9, perl = TRUE)
```

The edge case is infrequent but a feature of the vector that needs to be adjusted for.  There isn't a fixed number of digits to the left of the decimal (whether expressing $ or %) but there are always two decimals to the right of a decimal which makes me think conditionally approaching that is probably the way to go.

Here is a sample of a large piece of one element of the vector:

$28.00$25.0518.09%

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do it in two stages.  First insert a space after every second decimal.  Then remove the unwanted space this inserts before a `%`

```
x = '$28.00$25.0518.09%' 
y = gsub('(\\.\\d{2})', '\\1 ', x, perl = T) #insert space after decimals
trimws(gsub('\\s%', '% ', y))  # move space from before % to after %
# "$28.00 $25.05 18.09%"
```

This should also work for the more general cases @Julius described

```
x = "$28.00$25.0518.09%18.09%"  # "$28.00 $25.05 18.09% 18.09%"
x = "$28.00$25.0518.09%-7.10%$25.05-$25.05$25.05" # "$28.00 $25.05 18.09% -7.10% $25.05 -$25.05 $25.05"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.

```
gsub("(?<=\\.\\d{2})(?!%)", " ", "$28.00$25.0518.09%", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "$28.00 $25.05 18.09%"
```

We have a positive lookbehind `(?<=\\.\\d{2})` looking for a dot and two digits, and a negative lookahead `(?!%)` for %.

---

More generally, I guess you may also have "$28.00$25.0518.09%18.09%" in which case we need something else:

```
gsub("((?<=\\.\\d{2})|(?<=%))(?=[\\d$])", " ", "$28.00$25.0518.09%18.09%", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "$28.00 $25.05 18.09% 18.09%"
```

Now we have either a positive lookbehind for a dot and two digits or a positive lookbehind for %, and a positive lookahead for a digit or the end of a character.

---

If I understand correctly that your general problem is of the form "$28.00$25.0518.09%-7.10%$25.05-$25.05$25.05", then we may use almost the same solution as the latter one:

```
gsub("((?<=\\.\\d{2})|(?<=%))(?=[\\d$-])", " ", "$28.00$25.0518.09%-7.10%$25.05-$25.05$25.05", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "$28.00 $25.05 18.09% -7.10% $25.05 -$25.05 $25.05"
```

Comment: @js80, now I'm thinking that you also may have $28.00$25.0518.09%18.09%, right? I updated my answer.